# ssl сертификат для сайта в локальной сети

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, apache2

Что имеется:
- Linux Server на котором в Apache настроены сайты под домены, к примеру "test.mysite", "test1.mysite" ..., которые доступны только в локальной сети.
- Mikrotik, в котором прописаны адреса, чтобы на сайты можно было попасть любому пользователю в моей локальной сети.

На сайтах настроен HTTPS, но при переходе на сайт появляется сообщение, что сертификат недействителен.
Возможно ли, каким-то способом настроить HTTPS с действительным сертификатом? Не покупать же реальные сертификаты для сайтов в локальной сети.

Пробовал ставить сертификаты через mkcert, certbot и тому подобные.

Comment: Создайте сертификат с помощи openssl вот инструкция https://linux-notes.org/primery-ispol-zovaniya-openssl-v-unix-linux/

Comment: Для ненастоящих доменов не бывает настоящих сертификатов. Только принимать недействительные.

Answer (score 2):

Тут только два решения.

Используйте настоящие домены и получите сертификаты на letsencrypt для настоящих доменов.

Установите сертификат которым подписывали сертификаты доменов( при настройке https) как корневой центр сертификации на всех устройствах.